# Can port forwarding setting of router be effective if dhcp is disabled and ip address distributed by other device out of my control

Tags: networking, router, ftp, port-forwarding, dhcp-server

I want to set up a FTP server in my office computer.

I know that I have to forward port 21 and I could handle that in my home network.

But in my office computer, the router before my computer has disabled DHCP while the IP address are allocated by DHCP server which is out of my control.

Can I still set up port forwarding in my router or there is no means to set up FTP server if I have no control on the DHCP server?

Answer (score 1):

The solution to do what you wish, when you have no control over the local router, is to set up a **reverse tunnel**.

Firewalls are generally built in such a way that they block communications originating on the WAN side, while they allow instead communications originating on the LAN side. A reverse tunnel takes advantage of this by establishing a secure channel from within the LAN to some pc outside, so that, when you want to communicate **from** this outside pc **to** the LAN, you will find an ESTABLISHED, RELATED connection channel, which is already authorized by the firewall.

This is done by means of a Swiss-knife-like instrument of communication, **ssh**, which can not only initiate a communication from the LAN to the outside, but can also carry instructions to set up another, distinct channel to allow another type of communication. Since this is RELATED to an ESTABLISHED connection, it will be allowed by the router. This alternative channel will be encrypted (thus secure, one of the major advantages of using **ssh**), and can carry `any` form of communication: ftp, http, vnc, vpn, you name it (provided this payload uses TCP, not UDP).

Reverse tunnels can be set up in any OS, but the details vary from OS to OS, so I cannot be more specific. A Google search for your OS will allow you to find all needed material.

Answer (score 0):

No. Even if your router was forwarding port 21 alright, unfortunately it is not enough to forward just one port for FTP protocol to actually work.

This is in big contrast with many other protocols like HTTP or SSH which need only one TCP port forwarded (80 or 22). FTP nature is such that TCP port 21 is used for control purposes: to establish connection, to list files, to create or delete files, etc. But to transfer files, FTP needs to establish separate so called data connection which must use some other port number. Old scheme for data connection establishment is called active connection (very firewall unfriendly), and new scheme is called passive connection (better compatibility with firewalls, but still not ideal). In any case, you need to forward more than one port, and most likely whole range of ports. You can find out more about these FTP issues on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Transfer_Protocol).

Typical solution to overcome these FTP firewall complexities is to use other protocols that require only one TCP port to forward, like HTTP/HTTPS with WebDav, or SFTP (which has nothing in common with FTP, and is just an extension over SSH).